# pygame is not responding after playing an audio file

Tags: python, audio, tkinter, pygame

I'm newbie in pygame and not a very experienced python programmer,so hope you'll help. I'm trying to make my own audio player on python using pygame and tkinter. So there is my code:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.filedialog import *
import pygame
import sys
from pygame import*
mixer.init()
pygame.mixer.pre_init(44100, -16, 2, 2048)
def play(event):
    mixer.music.load("Chillingmusic.wav")
    mixer.music.play()
    while mixer.music.get_busy():
        time.Clock().tick(10)

def pause(event):
    pygame.mixer.music.pause()
    song.pause()

root=Tk()

txt=Text(root)

m=Menu(root)
root.config(menu=m)

fm=Menu(m)
m.add_cascade(label="File",menu=fm)
fm.add_command(label="Open",command_=open)

but=Button(text=">",bg="lightgreen")
but.grid(row=0,column=0)
but.bind("<Button-1>",play)

but1=Button(text="p",bg="lightblue")
but1.grid(row=0,column=1)
but1.bind("<Button-1>",pause)

root.mainloop()
pygame.quit()
```

Problem is when I start playing music by using play function audiofile is playing,but after that interface stop responding so I can't for example use my pause function.
I use python 3.6 and pygame 1.9.3 on Windows 10(64 bits).

Comment: The while loop in the `play` function will keep your main thread busy for the duration of the song. In other words, you cannot do anything until the while loop has finished. If you remove the while loop I think it should work as expected.

Comment: @TedKleinBergman your solution works. Why don't you post it as an answer?

Comment: @skrx Didn't have time to verify it myself so it was some guessing involved. It was more of a "try this and it might work" comment than an answer. I'll post a short answer now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `play` function will not finish until the song is finished. That means that your program has to wait for it to finish and cannot execute anything else during that time, making everything else unresponsive. Don't use the `while` loop.

```
def play(event):
    mixer.music.load("Chillingmusic.wav")
    mixer.music.play()
```

`mixer` is using another thread than your main thread, so the music will play and your own code can execute simultaneously.